# Xcode error The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached

Tags: xcode

I am under the age of 18 so I can't get into the Apple Developer program. I am forced to just use my free developer account and I have been for the past year. Today for some reason I am getting this error:

`The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.`

I've had a similar error to this before when I was creating new apps left and right and it said I had too much profiles for the week, so I waited and continued development. This error on the other hand isn't giving me any actions to fix the issue and I can't solve on myself.

Is there a way to possible delate some of the developer profiles that I have registered? Do I just need to wait a couple of days? I don't know what to do because the error message has no recommended action. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting your Mac date back a few days?  I don't know but it might trick Xcode and let you continue working.  Otherwise, I don't think you can get around this for the free account.  If you want to continue developing, without restrictions, you'll have to pay the $99.

Comment: I’m going to put this on hold. The premise that minors can’t get developer accounts has changed substantially - please flag or raise on [meta] if we can get this either corrected or linked to an equivalent question that’s more contemporary. I think leaving this up with the answers from the time is very helpful

Answer (score 55):

In my case [this guide](http://www.jianshu.com/p/99c441070b22) worked; that is, in Xcode go to `Window → Devices` then under `Installed Apps` delete some of your apps and afterwards I could run my own apps on the device again.

I also rebooted the phone beforehand, but I assume that was not necessary.

Comment: Worked for me!!(Y) No need to reboot

Comment: Yes, Right Answer and no need to reboot.

Answer (score 16):

I succeeded by removing all the unneeded provisioning profiles from the device itself.

1. In the Xcode Menu, go to Window → Devices.
2. Right-click the device that is giving the problem.
3. Choose **Show Provisioning Profiles** and delete some profiles to make room for new ones.

Comment: This worked for me, since I didn't have the apps installed, I just had the profiles. In fact, I had other development apps installed, but from other developers, not me.

Comment: the only solution that helped, thanks a lot @P5ycH0

Comment: Right, if You dont have installed apps, You still need to delete provisioning profiles.

Comment: This should be the right answer. If you delete apps from iPhone (and not remove the profiles), you'll experience such an error. So you need to remove **provisioning profiles**.

Comment: @MitrakovArtem, Even though I deleted the profiles and the installed apps, it still gives the error. Is there any other profiles I need to remove? I connected all my previous devices and deleted all profiles as well, but the error persists.

Comment: Huh, I connected another device and installed it just fine. This error only happens on one device, and I already removed all profiles and apps.

Answer (score 2):

So I went back to Xcode 7 and created a new app and tried to install it on my device and I found that it gave me the error that I can only make 10 apps per week. Xcode 8 must just not be able to give you that error message yet. Basically, I just need to wait for the week to be over.

Comment: please put this as a comment, and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had Provisioning Profiles on my device that I couldn't delete. Solution was going to `Window > Devices and Simulators`, then right-click your physical device and `Unpair Device`.

Pair your device again after, and the other provisional profiles that couldn't be removed are now gone.