# The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached

Tags: ios, applications, xcode

My question is an updated version of [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242678/xcode-error-the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-re) and I can't seem to find the way forward in this new version of XCode. I am new to Unity and XCode and had no idea there were a limited number of apps allotted to a personal development profile. Every time I screwed up a project trying to do [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml2UakwRxjk) I often struggled to fix it or made it worse (version and platform clash issues) so I started a new project without any idea it would count against some app count on my profile. I had no idea these unfinished doodles were considered apps. As I said, I'm a total newb in this realm! Now I've used all my apps and still don't have anything that works. How do I fix this? Thanks for your help.

This is the error I get from Xcode:
`The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.`

**Xcode version 11.4 (11E146)**

Comment: The question you linked to has a working answer.  Did you try that answer?

Comment: @fsb - I did and it did not. The interface has changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is delete these unfinished apps from your devices. Just delete them like you would any other app - directly on the phone.

You can also use the "Devices & Simulators" window in Xcode to delete them. If you have a lot, it is perhaps a bit faster.

If you have deleted the apps, but still get the error, then you need to remove the profiles themselves also. You can do that from the same "Devices & Simulators" window by right-clicking on the name of your iOS device, selecting "View Provisioning Profiles" and then removing them.

You can also do that on the device in Settings > General > Profile. Choose each no longer used profile and then "Remove".

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your help! I have deleted the apps and it still isn't working so I went into Settings > General, but did not find "Profile". I'm currently running iOS 13.4, and I wonder if the interface has changed?

Comment: Try opening "Devices & Simulators" in Xcode and right-click the name of your iOS device. Do you get the option to view the provisioning profiles?

Comment: Yes! That worked - thank you!! I deleted the profiles I found and have a new project up and running!

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 11.5 not posible to after complete maximum limit.
I have many try but not find any solution.

You add new account in XCode then you can easy to install app.

And you can perchase developer account in Apple.