# Unable to run self-developed app on my phone

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, xcode, developer-program

I built an app on my computer using xcode and I want to try running it on my iphone. Whenever I press run it shows me an error saying "Please delete apps signed with your free account from this device to remain under the limit." I don't know what it means. I checked other threads to see if there was a solution and I tried some things where I disconnected devices with my apple id, I unpaired my phone and then paired it again, etc. If anyone has any solution for my problem, I would seriously appreciate it.

[image: This is the error it shows.]

Comment: How many self-built/self-signed apps do you have on your phone?

Comment: Also: Please add links to the other things you've tried, and explain how exactly they failed. It will avoid answers proposing the same solutions, it will also help in understanding the issue.

Comment: @nohillside this is my first one so it is really weird.

Comment: @nohillside ok, i will add the links

Comment: I have tried all solutions in this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242678/xcode-error-the-maximum-number-of-apps-for-free-development-profiles-has-been-re

Comment: I have also tried what is on this website as well: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074

Comment: None of those will work @SreshtaTalluri see my answer for details on the three app limit. What version of Xcode are you running (then or now?)

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error on a freshly erased device, then the issue is your Apple ID and you will need to contact Apple Support.

More likely is you have three apps already loaded or [extra provisioning profiles lingering on the device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387445/5472) so delete one or more of your other apps and then try to install the app with which you get this error.

More details on this [over at stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61978102/475228) on app extensions and other apps that can be counted as free app installs by Xcode. Upgrading Xcode may fix this error as well.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_4-release-notes

> **Known Issues**
> When targeting devices running iOS 13.3.1, tvOS 13.3.1, watchOS 6.1, or later using a free Apple Developer account, app extensions incorrectly count against the limit of three apps installed simultaneously. When this happens, Xcode reports an error: “The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.” (59264389) (FB7568073)
> **Workaround**: Delete apps signed with your free account from your device and also remove any associated provisioning profiles from the device using Xcode’s Devices window. If your app contains more than two app extensions, remove them to remain under the three app limit